# instantly push event to ical calendar subscriber

Tags: php, outlook, calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I have created a code which generates .ics to synchronize events from my application to other calendar system like google, mac-ical, outlook etc.

I add url to these systems and all events from my application get synchronized.

This code does work fine but problem is event doesn't get synchronized instantly, it takes time to fetch events automatically.

So I want to make all events to get pushed to all subcribers, so that they get instantly updated, many applications do provide such things, in that I get instant update to my iCal on creating event.

So that is possible, I want to know how can I do it using php language, what technology I need to push events, instead of auto fetching by calendar system.

It will get general push to all subscribers not for any particular system like google calendar, I know it does have its own API.

Comment: Did you checked this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20918786/subscription-calendar-url-in-php

Comment: there is no instantly push.   The receiving applications determine how frequently they check for updates.  There is this https://icalendar.org/New-Properties-for-iCalendar-RFC-7986/5-7-refresh-interval-property.html  but I am not aware of how well observed these 'suggestions' are